# sass - create shorthand property from non shorthand properties

Tags: css, sass

does anyone know a solution - sass, npm, or whatever - to compose a shorthand form none shorthand properties?

for example:

```
padding-top: 10px;
pading-right: 20px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
padding-left: 40px;
```

should render to:

```
padding: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
```

I would prefer to explicit write all properties within my sass file but of course like to save the bytes in my css. Would be a big plus if there is also a way for background, border, ... and

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of to accomplish what you're wanting is to do something like this:

```
@mixin shorthand($props) {
  $keys: map-keys($props);
  $main: str-slice(nth($keys, 1), 0, str-index(nth($keys, 1), '-') - 1);
  $top: map-get($props, #{$main}-top);
  $right: map-get($props, #{$main}-right);
  $bottom: map-get($props, #{$main}-bottom);
  $left: map-get($props, #{$main}-left);

  #{$main}: $top $right $bottom $left;
}

.foobar {
  @include shorthand((
    padding-top: 10px,
    padding-right: 20px,
    padding-bottom: 30px,
    padding-left: 40px
  ));

  @include shorthand((
    margin-top: 10px,
    margin-right: 20px,
    margin-bottom: 30px,
    margin-left: 40px
  ));
}
```

Which results in:

```
.foobar {
  padding: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
  margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
}
```